# how to reset draggables that have been set to disable to restart a game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Using Edge Animate.
I have a game with a timer.
The user has to drag n drop objects in a certain amount of time.
I the user runs out of time, I want to reset everything.
I disable the draggable when they are dropped in the correct place in the drop event.

```
ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
```

However, when I reset all the elements, in the console I get the infamous:

```
**Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'**
```

Basically if I do not add

```
 sym.$(".set" + set).draggable( "enable" );
```

then the draggables are disabled.

But if I do not disable them then it causes a lot a problem to track answers and scores.

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Is there some work around or am I resetting things wrong? Or do I need to re

```
for (j = 0; j < logs1.length; j++) {
  sym.$(logs1[j]).addClass('logs1' + j);
  sym.$('.logs1' + j).draggable({
    zIndex: 1000,
    axis: "y",
    revert: function(obj) {
      if (obj === false) {
        sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop3");
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
      sym.$("water").show();
      startPos = $(this).offset().top;
      sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop1");
    }
  });
  sym.$('.logs1' + j).droppable({
    drop: function(ui, event) {
      $(this).css({
        'top': startPos
      });
    }
  });
  sym.$(droppable[j]).droppable({
    accept: ".logs1" + j,
    drop: dropEvent
  });
}
K = 0;

function dropEvent(event, ui) {
  $(this).css({'border': '3px solid lime'});
  logDropFX.play();
  ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'
  });
  waterRisingLoop.play();
  sym.getSymbol("beaver").stop("stop2");
  K++;
  sym.$("marker").animate({
    'top': 400 - (50 * K)
  }, 1000);
  var markerPos = sym.$("marker").offset().top;
  console.log("marker level: " + markerPos);
  if (markerPos < 250 || K == 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    done = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      sym.$('levelScreen').animate({
        "top": 0,
        'z-index': 99999
      }, 1000);
      sym.$("level").attr('src', 'images/level1Complete.png');
      sym.$(".set1").hide();
      levelUpFX.play();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

the code for the reset is the following. Redoing the draggables seems redundant. I tried with and without and still get the error message.

```
sym.$("startTimer").bind('click', function() {
 .... // some code before
  sym.$(".set" + set).show();
  for (j = 0; j < logs1.length; j++) {
      sym.$(('.logs' + set) + j).draggable();   // draggables
      sym.$(".set" + set).draggable("enable");  // re-enable
  }
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (w <= 180 && w > 0) {
      w = w - 3;
      sym.$("timer").css({
        "width": w
      });
      currentPos = (sym.$("water").offset().top) - 4;
      sym.$("water").animate({
        'top': currentPos
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution. I re-enabled the draggable in the drop event feedback check. So now I have (simplified):

```
function dropEvent(event, ui) {
  ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: 'left top',   at: 'left top'  });
  ui.draggable.addClass('done');
  K++;  
  if (markerPos < 250 || K == 5) {
    sym.$('.done').draggable('enable');    
  }
}
```